# angularjs how to load another controller without change the url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url, routes

I have one URL like `/products/:product_id`

And in this controller I check if the product id exists, and then, if don't exists, I want to load a controller which will display some text like "product not found".

I'm looking for some function like:

```
$location.path('/product_not_found');
```

but without change the URL in the bar

Any idea?

thanks!

Comment: I'm not a big expert at Angular, but did you try to check against that condition in your controller and print "Not found" instead of product?

Comment: Why do you need a separate controller to print 3 words?

Answer (score 0):

angularjs enables to add attributes to HTML tags. in case of displaying a product if found and message if not, i prefer to use `ng-show` attribute. for example:

by using ng-show you don't effect the URL because the content is already loaded.

**HTML:**

```
<html ng-app="productDisplay">
<head>
    <title>Product info</title>
    <script src="js/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content" ng-controller="ProductController as productCtrl">
        <div ng-show="status === 'waiting'">
            <p>waiting for product to load..</p>
        </div>
        <div ng-show="status === 'found'">
            <!-- display product info here -->
            <p>Name: {{ product.name }}</p>
            <p>Price: {{ product.price }}</p>
        </div>
        <div ng-show="status === 'not-found'">
            <p style="color: red;">Not found such product</p>   
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
(function() {
    // can access varibal app only in this function scope
    var app = angular.module('productDisplay', []);

    app.controller('ProductController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.product = {name: '', price: ''};
        $scope.status = 'waiting';

        this.getProduct = function() {
            found = false;

            /** some code checking if product found */

            if (!found) {
                $scope.status = 'not-found';
                return {};
            } else {
                $scope.status = 'found';
                return {name: 'BBB', price: '123$'};
            }
        };

        $scope.product = this.getProduct();
    }]);
})();
```